# JQGRID Should not refresh after post back

Tags: jqgrid

I am creating JQGRID in Code Behind and trying to call a WebMethod called 'GetUsersFromSP' and its working fine for me. I am getting the "loading..." text and i am getting the data. and when i click the "Load Grid" button its getting post back and reloading the data again from web service..Is that possible to hold the pervious data after post back and it should not hit the we service.Below is the code which i have tried. Kindly help me on this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string myString = "";
            myString = "window.onload = function() { ";
            myString += "jQuery(document).ready(function() {";

            myString += "        $('#list').jqGrid({";

            myString += "       url: 'WebService1.asmx/GetUsersFromSP',";
            myString += "       data: {},";
            myString += "       datatype: 'json',";
            myString += "       mtype: 'POST',";
            myString += "       ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },";
            myString += "       serializeGridData: function(postData) {";
            myString += "       if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;";
            myString += "       if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;";
            myString += "       if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;";
            myString += "       if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;";
            myString += "       return JSON.stringify(postData);";
            myString += "       },";
            myString += "       jsonReader: {";
            myString += "       root: function(obj) { return obj.d.rows; },";
            myString += "       page: function(obj) { return obj.d.page; },";
            myString += "       total: function(obj) { return obj.d.total; },";
            myString += "       records: function(obj) { return obj.d.records; }";
            myString += "       },";

            myString += "            colNames: ['UserID', 'UserName'],";
            myString += "            colModel: [";
            myString += "  { name: 'UserID', index: 'UserID', width: 80, align: 'left', editable: true },";
            myString += "  { name: 'UserName', index: 'UserName', width: 80, align: 'left', editable: true }],";
            myString += "            pager: jQuery('#pager'),";
            myString += "            rowList: [10, 20, 300],";
            myString += "            rowNum: 10,";
            myString += "            sortname: 'UserID',";
            myString += "            sortorder: 'asc',";
            myString += "            width: 400,";
            myString += "            viewrecords: true,";
            myString += "editurl:  'WebService1.asmx/ModifyData',";
            myString += "caption:  'My first grid'";
            myString += "        }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true }";

            //myString += "        { editData: { TableName: Inp1, ColumnValue: myArray} },";
            //myString += "        { editData: { TableName: Inp1, ColumnValue: myArray} });";
            myString += "        );";

            myString += "        jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {";
            myString += "            ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: 'application/json' },";
            myString += "            recreateForm: true,";
            myString += "            serializeEditData: function(postData) {";
            myString += "                if (postData.Col1 === undefined) { postData.Col1 = null; }";
            myString += "                myArray[0] = postData.Col1;";
            myString += "                myArray[1] = postData.Col2;";
            myString += "                myArray[2] = postData.Col3;";
            myString += "                return JSON.stringify(postData);";
            myString += "            }";
            myString += "        });";

            myString += "        jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.del, {";
            myString += "            ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: 'application/json' },";
            myString += "            serializeDelData: function(postData) {";
            myString += "                if (postData.Col1 === undefined) { postData.Col1 = null; }";
            myString += "                return JSON.stringify(postData);";
            myString += "            }";
            myString += "        });";

            myString += "    });";

            myString += "}";

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), myString, true);

    }
```

### CS FILE

[WebMethod]
public JQGridResults GetUsersFromSP(string searchField, string searchOper, string searchString, string filters, string _search, string nd, string rows, string page, string sidx, string sord)
        {
            int totalRecords=0;
            string strSearchCondition = null;
            Collection users = new Collection();
            Hashtable getoperator = new Hashtable();

```
        Hashtable inParams = new Hashtable();
        inParams.Add("@CONDITION", strSearchCondition);
        inParams.Add("@SORTCONDITION", " order by " + sidx + " " + sord);
        inParams.Add("@PAGE", page);
        inParams.Add("@ROWS", rows);
        inParams.Add("@RECORDCOUNT", totalRecords);

        Hashtable outParams = new Hashtable();
        outParams.Add("@RECORDCOUNT", totalRecords);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int rVal;
        ds = GetDataSet(vzaiConn, "SPNAME", out rVal, inParams, out outParams);
        totalRecords = (int)outParams["@RECORDCOUNT"];
        JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults();
        List<JQGridRow> rows1 = new List<JQGridRow>();
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow user in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow();
                row.id = (int)user["UserID"];
                row.cell = new string[6];
                row.cell[0] = user["UserID"].ToString();
                row.cell[1] = user["UserName"].ToString();
                row.cell[2] = user["FirstName"].ToString();
                row.cell[3] = user["MiddleName"].ToString();
                row.cell[4] = user["LastName"].ToString();
                row.cell[5] = user["EmailID"].ToString();
                rows1.Add(row);
            }
            result.rows = rows1.ToArray();
            result.page = Convert.ToInt32(page);
            result.total = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalRecords / (decimal)Convert.ToDecimal(rows));
            result.records = Convert.ToInt32(totalRecords);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi friend try this :-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        string myString = "";
        myString = "window.onload = function() { ";
        myString += "jQuery(document).ready(function() {";

        myString += "        $('#list').jqGrid({";

        myString += "       url: 'WebService1.asmx/GetUsersFromSP',";
        myString += "       data: {},";
        myString += "       datatype: 'json',";
        myString += "       mtype: 'POST',";
        myString += "       ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },";
        myString += "       serializeGridData: function(postData) {";
        myString += "       if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;";
        myString += "       if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;";
        myString += "       if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;";
        myString += "       if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;";
        myString += "       return JSON.stringify(postData);";
        myString += "       },";
        myString += "       jsonReader: {";
        myString += "       root: function(obj) { return obj.d.rows; },";
        myString += "       page: function(obj) { return obj.d.page; },";
        myString += "       total: function(obj) { return obj.d.total; },";
        myString += "       records: function(obj) { return obj.d.records; }";
        myString += "       },";

        myString += "            colNames: ['UserID', 'UserName'],";
        myString += "            colModel: [";
        myString += "  { name: 'UserID', index: 'UserID', width: 80, align: 'left', editable: true },";
        myString += "  { name: 'UserName', index: 'UserName', width: 80, align: 'left', editable: true }],";
        myString += "            pager: jQuery('#pager'),";
        myString += "            rowList: [10, 20, 300],";
        myString += "            rowNum: 10,";
        myString += "            sortname: 'UserID',";
        myString += "            sortorder: 'asc',";
        myString += "            width: 400,";
        myString += "            viewrecords: true,";
        myString += "editurl:  'WebService1.asmx/ModifyData',";
        myString += "caption:  'My first grid'";
        myString += "        }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true }";

        //myString += "        { editData: { TableName: Inp1, ColumnValue: myArray} },";
        //myString += "        { editData: { TableName: Inp1, ColumnValue: myArray} });";
        myString += "        );";

        myString += "        jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {";
        myString += "            ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: 'application/json' },";
        myString += "            recreateForm: true,";
        myString += "            serializeEditData: function(postData) {";
        myString += "                if (postData.Col1 === undefined) { postData.Col1 = null; }";
        myString += "                myArray[0] = postData.Col1;";
        myString += "                myArray[1] = postData.Col2;";
        myString += "                myArray[2] = postData.Col3;";
        myString += "                return JSON.stringify(postData);";
        myString += "            }";
        myString += "        });";

        myString += "        jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.del, {";
        myString += "            ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: 'application/json' },";
        myString += "            serializeDelData: function(postData) {";
        myString += "                if (postData.Col1 === undefined) { postData.Col1 = null; }";
        myString += "                return JSON.stringify(postData);";
        myString += "            }";
        myString += "        });";

        myString += "    });";

        myString += "}";

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), myString, true);
 }
}
```

This is not help for you please Send Clear description

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I also tried with Ispostback....but the grid is no appering after the post back. The page which i am working had html table with pagination of records fetched from DB and i am trying to change that html table to JQGRID now...And in the same page i have lots of submit button and when i click those buttons its refreshing the page as well as JQGRID. My question is their any way that we can maintain the (previous values as such) state of the grid and refresh the page after the Post Back.